# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I'm working to built a contact list that is grouped by the first letter of the contact's last name.

After a succesfull ajax request, the contact is pushed to addContact:

**Ajax success:**

```
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(dataJS.contactList, function(c) {
        contactsModel.addContact(c);
    });
```

**contactsModel.addContact:**

```
//add a contact in the right spot under the right letter
contactsModel.addContact = function(newContact) {
    //grab first character
    var firstLetter = (newContact.lname || "").charAt(0).toUpperCase();
    //if it is a number use #
    if (!isNaN(firstLetter)) {
        firstLetter = "#";
    }

    //do we already have entries for this letter
    if (!this.letterIndex[firstLetter]) {
    //new object to track this letter's contacts
        var letterContacts = {
            letter: firstLetter,
            contacts: ko.observableArray([])
        };

        this.letterIndex[firstLetter] = letterContacts; //easy access to it

        //put the numbers at the end
        if (firstLetter === "#") {
            this.contactsByLetter.push(letterContacts);
        } else {
            //add the letter in the right spot 
            for (var i = 0, lettersLength = this.contactsByLetter().length; i < lettersLength; i++) {
                var letter = this.contactsByLetter()[i].letter;

                if (letter === "#" || firstLetter < letter) {
                     break;  
                }
            }  
            this.contactsByLetter.splice(i, 0, letterContacts);
        }
    }

    var contacts = this.letterIndex[firstLetter].contacts;

    //now we have a letter to add our contact to, but need to add it in the right spot
    var newContactName = newContact.lname + " " + newContact.fname;
    for (var j = 0, contactsLength = contacts().length; j < contactsLength; j++) {
        var contactName = contacts()[j].lName + " " + contacts()[j].fName;

        if (newContactName < contactName) {
           break;  
        }
    }

    //add the contact at the right index
    contacts.splice(j, 0, newContact);

}.bind(contactsModel);
```

The contacts json object from the server looks like this:

```
{
        "total_pages": 10,
        "page": page,
        "contactList": [{
            "photo": "http://homepage.mac.com/millhouse/Family%20Tree/images/PersonListIcon.png",
            "lname": "Bond",
            "id": 241,
            "fname": "James",
            "email": "xxx@yahoo.com"},
```

While this works in jsfiddle, when I try it locally, I get the following error during the first push to addContact:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
jQuery.jQuery.extend._Deferred.deferred.resolveWithjquery-1.5.1.js:869
donejquery-1.5.1.js:6591
jQuery.ajaxTransport.send.callbackjquery-1.5.1.js:7382
```

Ideas? Thanks

Comment: On your local machine, after `var contacts = this.letterIndex[firstLetter].contacts;` do a `console.log(contacts)` and make sure that contacts is the right object you are trying to use.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax looks wrong in the `for` loops and elsewhere, that is `()` meant for invoking functions.  Try changing everywhere you have `contactsByLetter()` and `contacts()` to `contactsByLetter` and `contacts`.

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't seem to do the trick. Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bhellman1/NV4Nu/2/

Comment: What I can't get is why it works in the fiddle but errors for me

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you wrap your bindings statement in a jQuery ready...

```
$(function(){
    ko.applyBindings(contactsModel, document.getElementById("view-panel-contacts"));
});
```

That worked for me using the code you provided in the fiddle.

http://pastebin.com/YYfBB0ES