# jQuery UI Tabs "Select" Event Being Overridden by "Click" Event -- Uncaught TypeError

Tags: jquery, tabs, jquery-ui-tabs, typeerror

I'm having some trouble selecting a tab programmatically. My tabs are loading inside a Fancybox dialog window, which is launched on click of a link. Basically, I want to perform certain actions any time a tab is selected, and also select a specific tab when a link is clicked.

I am initializing jQuery UI Tabs with the `select` event like so:

```
$('#tabs').tabs({

    select: function(event, ui) {

        // edit: here is the issue
        var activePanel = '.ui-tabs-panel:visible ';

        // grab value of a form input
        var text = $(activePanel + 'someElement').val();

        // check its length
        if ( text.length > 0 ) {
           // do stuff
        }
    }
})
```

Later on in my JS file I have the following:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.edit', function() {
    if($category == 'book') {
        // load the tab specific to the 'book' category
        $('#tabs').tabs({ selected: 3 });
    }
})
```

When I click the `a.edit` link for an item in the "book" category, my console throws this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

Then, instead of the tabs loading in the Fancybox, nothing happens. This error is *not* thrown when I click the link for items that are not in the book category. Thus, two things are painfully evident:

1. I am a n00b
2. My `select` event is apparently getting overridden by the click event, so `text` is not set

I've tried setting a default for `text` at the top of my JS file but that doesn't work. My question, then, is:

**What is the correct way to initialize UI Tabs with a select event, while also being able to programmatically select a tab with a click event?**

Or, more concisely,

**Why am I getting that damn error?**

*Edit: I amended my first code block above to include code that I discovered was relevant to my problem. See my answer below for a fuller explanation.*

Comment: Hiya cool so what is $category there must be a syntax error bruv which leads to this further read this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6011731/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-length-of-undefined :) have a nice one, cheerios!

Comment: Can you create a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to demo your problem?

Comment: @Tats_innit, Ayman Safadi -- thanks for your comments! Your suggestions led me to reevaluate my code and discover the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered the problem: I am indeed a n00b.

I was setting the `text` variable based on whether or not the tab was visible. Because my tabs were hidden by default, there was never a visible panel from which to grab a value.

I solved the problem by adding a simple check to see if the parent element was visible before assigning the variable:

```
if ( $('#tab_container').is(':visible') ) {

    // now we can safely set this variable...
    var activePanel = '.ui-tabs-panel:visible ';

    // ...and this will always have a value
    var text = $(activePanel + 'someElement').val();
}
```